# onItemClickListener won't work with checkbox

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView with a custom adapter. The ListView will contain a list of checkboxes and each time a checkbox is clicked I want to add/remove the checkbox from an array inside my custom view, so I thought the best way to achieve this would be to use the onItemClickListener.

The thing is that this doesn't work, the code in the onItemClickListener never runs. I found many questions on SO about the same problem, but the solution that worked for them didn't work for me.

This is my code:

MultichoiceAnswerView.java

```
private void init(Context context) {
    multichoiceAdapter = new MultichoiceAdapter(context, alternatives);

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_answer_multichoice, this);

    listAlternatives = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_alternatives);
    listAlternatives.setAdapter(multichoiceAdapter);
    // This is where I tried to add a onItemClickListener, with no success. 

    super.init();
}
```

MultichoiceAdapter.java

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    String alternative = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_multichoice, parent, false);
    }

    CheckBox checkBoxAlternative = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_alternative);
    checkBoxAlternative.setText(alternative);

    return convertView;
}
```

view_answer_multichoice.xml

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_alternatives"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

item_multichoice.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox_alternative"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Answer"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The project can be accessed in this GitHub repo (branch "cards"): https://github.com/WeeRox/yaffect-android

The solution I've tried:
Setting `focusable="false"` on the checkbox. 
Setting `focusableInTouchMode="false"` on the checkbox (both with and without `focusable="false"`)
Setting `descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to the LinearLayout
Setting `checkBoxAlternative.setFocusable(false);` in the adapter (didn't try the other things though)

None of the above mentioned solutions worked. 
I did find a (obvious) way to fix this by setting `clickable="false"` on the checkbox, but if I can get this to work without having to programmatically check the box it would be great.

Maybe there is a clean workaround that I haven't thought of (maybe I could use a RecyclerView or something like that). 
So, how would I fix this?
And why did the above mentioned solution not work for me?

Comment: `setOnCheckedChangeListener` have u tried?

Comment: @phpdroid Well, wouldn't I need to do that on the checkbox itself? Because I can set an `onClickListener` on the checkbox that will work too, but since I want to be able to store currently checked boxes in an array inside my custom view that wont really serve its purpose.